# https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic InRelease 403 Forbidden

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I have the following errors:

```
Err:14 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic InRelease 
 403  Forbidden [IP: 35.161.110.43 443] 
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian/dists/bionic/InRelease 
 403  Forbidden [IP: 35.161.110.43 443] 
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have the following `/etc/apt/sources.list` file content:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
```

I searched for any solution, but could not find one.

Any idea?

Thank you

p.s: Important to know, I don't have a graphical interface, I only use the command line

Comment: Did you check in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory?  It's empty on a new install, but sources added into that directory are used to by your system, the file metadata will tell you when a user with `sudo` rights added those lines to your system.

Comment: Thanks, I m not sure what do you mean by "the file metadata", here is the content of sources.list.d: brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng-bionic.list       ondrej-ubuntu-php-bionic.list  rabbitmq.list.save
brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng-bionic.list.save  rabbitmq.list

Comment: Each of those files has been added by a user on your system with `sudo` rights..  From the file names your error *likely* exists in rabbitmq.list but we cannot read the contents of those files, being limited to what you provide. The file's date/time details (`stat` or view creation/modification dates will tell you when added to your system; ie. metadata about the file stored on your file-system)

Comment: Originally filed in 2017 but it's worth mentioning that Bintray has been permanently shut down in May 2021. See the README of this package to find out how the package is distributed these days. Take a look into this url for more info
https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/issues/55 The process of migration here:
https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2021/03/migrate-off-of-bintray/ Edit:
Resume of what needs to be done
https://averyuslaner.com/fixing-rabbitmq-sources-repository/